# Perform calculation on several sublists using Map

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I am trying to perform a calculation on a list containing sublists.
More exact: The x-axis values are time data, progressing from zero, the y-axis data are data points, which I want to normalize. I want the y data to have their minimum at zero. Therefore, I look for the smallest y value in each sublist and add or subtract (depending if it is positive or negative) from all other y values of that sublist. I want to perform the calculation for all sublists.
I think I haven't quite understood what the Slot ([`#`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html)) exactly does?!

I post here just an example list illustrating my problem, since the real list is very long.

My approach:

```
list={{{0,-0.1},{1,0.5},{2,0.7},{3,1.2},{4,0.6},{5,0.5},{6,1.3}},{{0,0.1},{1,0.5},{2,0.3},{3,0.7},{4,0.8},{5,1.1},{6,1.2}}}

list//{#[[1]],(#[[2]]-Min[#[[All,2]]])}&/@#&
```

This approach gives the following errors:

> Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist. >>
>
> Part::partw: Part 2 of {} does not exist. >>
>
> Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of Part::partw will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

Comment: You might be interested in `Rescale[]`.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know that command. But just out of interest, is there a way to solve my problem with something similar I tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your code does not return an error on my machine.

Second, using "something similar to what you tried", you might want to do

```
Transpose[{#[[All, 1]], #[[All, 2]] - Min[#[[All, 2]]]}] & /@ list
```

Answer (score 5):

Just based on your text:

```
f[u_] := Module[{a, b}, {a, b} = Transpose@u; 
  Transpose[{a, b - Min@b}]]
```

`f/@list` yields:

> {{{0, 0.}, {1, 0.6}, {2, 0.8}, {3, 1.3}, {4, 0.7}, {5, 0.6}, {6, 
>      1.4}}, {{0, 0.}, {1, 0.4}, {2, 0.2}, {3, 0.6}, {4, 0.7}, {5, 
>      1.}, {6, 1.1}}}

Comment: Puh, thanks a lot for the answer, it's very elegant. I have to wrap my head round it! I'm not very familiar with such constructs.

Comment: @Niki just play around...essentially transposing rectangular array allows you deal with columns as you like then re: transposing restores initial configuration with transformed rows...play and enjoy:)

Answer (score 1):

```
  list =
      {{{0, -0.1}, {1, 0.5}, {2, 0.7}, {3, 1.2}, {4, 0.6}, {5, 0.5}, {6, 1.3}}, 
        {{0, 0.1}, {1, 0.5}, {2, 0.3}, {3, 0.7}, {4, 0.8}, {5, 1.1}, {6, 1.2}}};
```

Using `Threaded` (new in 13.1)

```
# - Threaded[{0, Min @ #[[All, 2]]}] & /@ list
```

returns

```
{{{0, 0.}, {1, 0.6}, {2, 0.8}, {3, 1.3}, {4, 0.7}, {5, 0.6}, {6, 1.4}}, 
 {{0, 0.}, {1, 0.4}, {2, 0.2}, {3, 0.6}, {4, 0.7}, {5, 1.0}, {6, 1.1}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Outer` and `Transpose`:

```
list =
  {{{0, -0.1}, {1, 0.5}, {2, 0.7}, {3, 1.2}, {4, 0.6}, {5, 0.5}, {6, 1.3}}, 
    {{0, 0.1}, {1, 0.5}, {2, 0.3}, {3, 0.7}, {4, 0.8}, {5, 1.1}, {6, 1.2}}};

Transpose/@Transpose@{#[[All, All, 1]], #[[All, All, 2]]
- Outer[Min, #[[All, All, 2]], 1]} &@list

{{{0, 0.}, {1, 0.6}, {2, 0.8}, {3, 1.3}, {4, 0.7}, {5, 0.6}, {6, 1.4}}, 
 {{0, 0.}, {1, 0.4}, {2, 0.2}, {3, 0.6}, {4, 0.7}, {5, 1.0}, {6, 1.1}}}
```